# Extension method to run in parallel a Task for a certain amount of minutes

Tags: c#, task

I managed to make that extension just with `Action` in a sync context. The final result I obtained is to call a method like this:

```
const int minutesPerTest = 5;
var result = minutesPerTest.ExecuteFor(new MyTestClass().Call);
```

The extensions I created are:

```
public static TimeMetric ExecuteFor(this Action methodToMeasure, int minutes = 1)
{
    var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
    var timeMetric = new TimeMetric();
    int callsNumber = 0;

    stopWatch.Start();
    while (stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalMinutes < minutes)
    {
        ++callsNumber;
        methodToMeasure();
    }
    stopWatch.Stop();

    timeMetric.TotalElapsed = stopWatch.Elapsed;
    timeMetric.AvgElapsed = timeMetric.TotalElapsed.Divide(callsNumber);

    return timeMetric;
}

public static TimeMetric ExecuteFor(this int minutes, Action methodToMeasure)
    => methodToMeasure.ExecuteFor(minutes);
```

I use this to make some very simple "profiling" and comparisons between methods.

---

What I'd like to do, is the same but instead of `Action` use `Task` and call every my `Task` in parallel.

The final result should be:

```
const int minutesPerTest = 5;
var result = minutesPerTest.ExecuteForInParallel(new MyTestClass().CallAsync);
```

I tried:

```
public static TimeMetric ExecuteForInParallel(this Func<CancellationToken, Task> methodToMeasure, int minutes = 1)
{
    var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
    var timeMetric = new TimeMetric();

    var tasks = new List<Task>();
    var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

    stopWatch.Start();

    cancellationTokenSource.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(minutes));

    while (!cancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        tasks.Add(methodToMeasure(cancellationTokenSource.Token));
    }

    stopWatch.Stop();

    int callsNumber = tasks.Count(t => t.IsCompleted);
    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

    timeMetric.TotalElapsed = stopWatch.Elapsed;
    timeMetric.AvgElapsed = timeMetric.TotalElapsed.Divide(callsNumber);

    return timeMetric;
}

public static TimeMetric ExecuteForInParallel(this int minutes, Func<CancellationToken, Task> methodToMeasure)
    => methodToMeasure.ExecuteForInParallel(minutes);
```

The first problem I noticed is that when the code arrives at `Task.WaitAll`, it seems that in the `while` loop it has created too many tasks, and the final `Wait` takes a lot of time. I thought that the cancellation token would abort them all instantly, but this isn't happening. If I didn't wait for all the created tasks to complete, the next time I call the same extension no task will start because there a lot of them "in queue".

An example of `CallAsync` I'm using, (It's just an example, to represent an http call):

```
public async Task CallAsync(CancellationToken token)
{
    if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
        return;

    var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
    request.AddQueryParameter("EventID", _event.ToString());
    IRestResponse response = await _client.ExecuteTaskAsync(request, token);

    if (response.StatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
        throw new Exception($"Error! Response: {response.StatusCode}");
}
```

`_client` is an http client from `RestSharp` library. I correctly see a lot of `TaskCanceledException` in the output window while debugging at the end of `minutes` of execution.

How can I kill all the scheduled tasks without making my extension hang?

Comment: `CancellationToken` is for cooperative cancellation. That means the method (`CallAsync` in this case) should check if cancellation requested (and pass that token to method it calls which accept it) and gracefully exit (or throw task cancelled exception). It's perfectly possible that given task will finish much later than you cancelled token, and it might ignore that token completely. Also, I doubt you intend to queue thousands of tasks which you do now by adding them in a loop without any waiting.

Comment: Cancellation is *cooperative*. The cancellation token doesn't do anything by itself. Code within the task has to be *monitoring* the token and react to cancellation.

Comment: But why do you need to schedule all those thousands of tasks in the first place?

Comment: I want to call `CallAsync` in parallel as much as my machine can. Maybe there is a better way to see the requirement...

Comment: Well you can start new threads yourself to avoid using thread pool (this is what queues those tasks), but each thread reserves at least 1MB for stack so you will won't be able to run thousands of them.